# Javascript file.type is not working on IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload, mime-types

I am trying to check the file type in javascript and my code is:

`file.type.match('application/pdf')`

```
function checkPropertyFileValidity(){
        var property_file_input = document.getElementById('property_file');
                if(!jQuery('.property_doc_div .property_doc_icon').hasClass("hidden")) {
            jQuery('.property_doc_div .property_doc_icon').addClass("hidden");
        }
        if (property_file_input.files && property_file_input.files[0]) {
            var property_file = property_file_input.files[0];
            jQuery('.property_doc_div .remove_selected_file').removeClass('hidden');
            if(property_file.type.match('application/pdf') && property_file.size <= 5242880) {
                console.log(property_file.type.match('application/pdf'));
                                jQuery('.help-inline.property_file_error').html('');
                jQuery('.property_doc_div #property_doc_icon').attr("title",property_file.name);
                jQuery('.property_doc_div .property_doc_icon').removeClass("hidden");
                return true;
            } else if(!property_file.type.match('application/pdf')) {
                                console.log(property_file.type.match('application/pdf'));
                jQuery('.help-inline.property_file_error').html('You can select only pdf files');
                return false;
            } else if(property_file.size > 5242880) {
                jQuery('.help-inline.property_file_error').html('File can not be greater than 5 MB');
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Following is the version of my IE 11
[image]

and doing file.type gives empty string. 
Now this thing works good for chrome , Firefox and on IE 10 but not on IE 11. Kindly help me !!!

Comment: what do you get if you console.log(file.type); ?

Comment: @atmd it returns null

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code or add to a fiddle.

Comment: Is working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6fthqu7n/ any error in the console? Can the pdf be corrupted?

Comment: It is also working fine for me in IE11.

Comment: @JRulle its working fine for me too. Even on IE 11 Version 11.0.96.1663 its working fine. But its not working fine for one specific version of IE 11 that I have mentioned above. It give console.log(file.type) empty

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't really help you troubleshoot an issue we can't reproduce. Sorry.

Comment: It's also failing for me in 11.0.9600.17498. Curious if you ever found a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE 11 and IE Edge get file.type failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849014/ie-11-and-ie-edge-get-file-type-failed)