# IE 11 and IE Edge get file.type failed

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

```
"change .btn-file :file"       : "getfileinfo",

getfileinfo: function(e){

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileupload');
    var file = fileInput.files[0];

    if(!file || (file.type != 'text/plain' && file.type != 'text/csv' && file.type != 'application/csv' && file.type != 'application/vnd.ms-excel' && file.type != 'text/csv')){
        $('.alert-file').show();
        $('.alert-file').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
        return false;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#fileData').val(reader.result);
        $('#fileName').val(file.name); 

    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}
```

`file.type` is null if i used in IE11 and IE Edge. All other browser working fine.

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Also do some mindstorm before asking .Have you not seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980428/javascript-file-type-is-not-working-on-ie-11

Comment: Yep i saw but there is no answer

Comment: I'm not seeing `null`; can you test http://jsfiddle.net/w7dLjvxt/?

Comment: Did u check IE EDGE ? I am testing in win10 IE edge. 

Even i test ur code [object File]{lastModifiedDate: date, name: "sample.csv", size: 236, type: ""} . see the console

Comment: Yes, I checked both the RTM (10240) build, and my own *internal* build (I'm an engineer on the Edge team). Both showed a valid mime-type. I even tested a .csv, and on my RTM machine I got "application/vnd.ms-excel". I'm not sure what you mean by "IE EDGE" though. IE and Edge are two distinctly different browsers.

Comment: Thanks For the answer . Sorry i am testing in Edge on Windows 10. I received empty i am not sure why its happening.

Comment: @Sampson is there any setting blocking my file type. i am pretty sure its working in all other browser and IE 7,8,9. only Edge and IE11 giving issue.

Comment: @atmd  you also face this problem before. Did u manage to find the solution.

Comment: @Sampson Forget to mentioned . I am using Parellel Desktop to Connect Windows 10

Comment: O got same problem here in EDGE and IE11.

Comment: @Gopi: did you find answer to your question? I am facing same issue with IE 11 on windows 7

Comment: I have the same problem on Edge and Firefox. Not sure are they using the same mime type data source but they can't detect .zip file.

Answer (score 6):

Test case

```html
<input type="file" onchange="document.body.innerText = this.files[0].type" />
```

returns MIME for SVG, PNG, ZIP, but returns `""` for PDF

Reproduced on IE11 under Windows 8.1 Pro x64

```
Version: 11.0.9600.18053
Update Versions: 11.0.24 (KB3093983)
```

Bug already reported and closed with "could not reproduce" https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/2009205. It mentions why IE team can not reproduce:

> Keep in mind that IE can only determine the MIME type of a file based on its extension when a handler application for that MIME type (e.g. Adobe Reader) is installed on the system and creates the mapping inside the registry's HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT registry hive. If no mapping exists in the registry, then IE has no way to know what MIME type the file is.

Among 20 GB of freshly installed Windows there was no space to put `file` tool

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: @Bonatti It was not possible to reproduce, I've cleaned up test case (source code clarity and file type), described exact environment, should help

Comment: An answer in stackoverflow should be a way for the OP to fix his/her issue,  or a way to find documentation to understand the problem.... your answer is neither, and should a new comer check your "answer", he would still not understand what to do...[Please, read this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: At least he believes his eyes when see bug in newest and glorious IE. The only **real** answer is from IE Team - fixing the bug. This requires attention and test case. That's all I can do

Comment: Isn't being told "It may never be filled in" an answer when asking why `file.type` is empty? That way, a developer can determine that they must use an alternative hack of their choosing, or drop the feature in favor of something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this error on the free Windows 7 / IE 11 VM ([available here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwimwZX5huDQAhVMDsAKHRIYAkcQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fmicrosoft-edge%2Ftools%2Fvms%2F&usg=AFQjCNFvaneiFHlrnd1P6jvUhYSfYEvxjg&sig2=SAOIViEGWiuknNe7XA3u0g)), which crucially does NOT come with a default PDF handler and so does not know what the mimetype is.

As a result, the only workaround I came up with was this (as an example for PDF files - change application/pdf and pdf as needed):

```
if(file.type == 'application/pdf' || file.name.toLowerCase().endsWith('pdf'))
{
    //code to execute
}
```

Note that this won't work without the polyfill for endsWith on all versions of IE - so here is the polyfill snippet which you need to include anywhere in your code (which comes from the [Mozilla page here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith))

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(searchString, position) {
      var subjectString = this.toString();
      if (typeof position !== 'number' || !isFinite(position) || Math.floor(position) !== position || position > subjectString.length) {
        position = subjectString.length;
      }
      position -= searchString.length;
      var lastIndex = subjectString.lastIndexOf(searchString, position);
      return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
  };
}
```